# How to make font bigger?

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts, jframe

[image]

I try to make upn logo use JFrame. I make 3shape successly and I make upn letter but I can't make bigger how to make font bigger?

Pleas help me.
this is my code

```
   package test;

   import java.awt.*;

   import java.awt.Font;

   import javax.swing.*;

   public class UPN extends JPanel {


   public static void main(String[] args) {

   JFrame window = new JFrame("UPN");

   UPN content = new UPN();

   window.setContentPane(content);

   window.setSize(400,400);

   window.setLocation(100,100);

   window.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

   window.setVisible(true);

   }
   private Font font;

   public void paint(Graphics g) {  

     g.setColor(Color.RED);
     g.fillRect(250,100,100,100);

     g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        int xpoints[] = {200, 140, 270};
        int ypoints[] = {80, 200, 200};
        int npoints = 3;
     g.fillPolygon(xpoints, ypoints, npoints);


     g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
     g.fillOval(63,100,100,100);

g.setColor(Color.black);
g.drawString("UPN", 30, 150);


    }
   public void letter(){
       font=new Font("Helvetica",Font.BOLD,150);
        setFont(font);
   }
```

}

Comment: Please try to format code blocks properly. The post is very ugly and hard to read as is.

Comment: Did you have a look the `Font(name, style, size)` constructor you're already using? (Or at least it is in your code, I don't see you calling the `letter()` method anywhere.)

Comment: I'm not yet try Font(name, style, size).Where need to add Font(name, style, size) code>

Comment: You did try this (`new Font("Helvetica",Font.BOLD,150)`). Please give my suggestion a try, and simply add a call to the `letter()` method before you drawString

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line:

```
setFont(new Font("Helvetica", 1, 170));
```

Comment: I think the issue is that OP never called his code that does this.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to just draw the jpeg or png to a JPanel and then add that to the Jframe. But if you want/need to keep using this, Java Oracle has all the methods relating to Font and how they work. You should look there for  questions like this one.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html

Answer (score 0):

I notice you never called your `letter()` function. Try that first.

Instead of:

```
g.setColor(Color.black);
g.drawString("UPN", 30, 150);
```

Delete the `letter` method and try:

```
g.setColor(Color.black);
setFont(new Font("Helvetica", 1, 170));
g.drawString("UPN", 30, 150);
```

You defined `letter()`, which will do what you want, but you never use it.

Comment: Pleas explain detail.I can't understand.Sorry

Comment: hmmm, try my edit instead. Not sure why it didn't work the first time.

Comment: I'm not sure then, sorry. @Ngima Sherpa tried the same and claims it worked.